# Firebase phone authentication with invisible captcha setup fires twice by design?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I was following the firebase guide for phone authentication with invisible captcha: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#use-invisible-recaptcha

> To use an invisible reCAPTCHA, create a RecaptchaVerifier object with the size parameter set to invisible, **specifying the ID of the button that submits your sign-in form**. [...]

1. So I need a sign in form that accepts phone number. On submit, I'll run the `mySignInWithPhoneNumberFormSubmit` function:

```js
import { signInWithPhoneNumber } from "firebase/auth";

function mySignInWithPhoneNumberFormSubmit(){
  // ...
  signInWithPhoneNumberForm(auth, phoneNumber, appVerifier).then(...);
  // ...
}
```

```html
<!-- excerpt. Not actual Angular code -->
<form onsubmit="mySignInWithPhoneNumberFormSubmit()">
  Enter phone: <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" id="sign-in-button">
</form>
```

2. The guide also asks to specify the form submit button id in the captcha initializer:

```js
import { getAuth, RecaptchaVerifier } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
  'size': 'invisible',
  'callback': (response) => {
    mySignInWithPhoneNumberFormSubmit();
  }
}, auth);
```

So this seem to be running twice (I verified with some console.logs and traces). Is this the expected behaviour?

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-dn2uyv?file=index.html

*(firebase emulator log, each time with different codes)*
[image: firebase emulator log for the above issue]

Comment: The point is the `mySignInWithPhoneNumberFormSubmit` fires twice by this design right? 1. while forms submits, 2. while captcha passes.